# Rails Tutorial - Chapter 8 deployment issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I have started learning Ruby on Rails via Michael Hartl's tutorial. Having completed chapter 8, the app works as expected on a local server. However, once deployed to Heroku, the dropdown menu fails to load. If I inspect the dropdown in browser, this is what I find:
[dropdown_inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaSSO.png)

I have followed various suggestions in other answers, such as changing the ordering of application.js from what was in the tutorial so that //require rails-ujs was listed prior to //=require bootstrap but to no avail. This is the relevant code snippet from _header.html.erb:

```html
<% if logged_in? %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Users", '#' %>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Profile", current_user %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Settings", '#' %>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <% else %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
```

and from sessions_helper.rb:

```
def current_user
 if (user_id = session[:user_id])
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
 elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
   user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
   if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
     log_in user
     @current_user = user
   end
 end
end
```

Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not your question, but you have single `=` (for assigning a value) when you want `==`  (checking equality) in both the if and elsif conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not where the error lies as per the tutorial explanation: Despite appearances, this is not a comparison (which would use double-equals ==), but rather is an assignment. If you were to read it in words, you wouldn’t say “If user id equals session of user id…”, but rather something like “If session of user id exists (while setting user id to session of user id)…”.10

Comment: Have you tried precompiling assets using "rails assets:precompile"? then pushing again to Heroku?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply as I have been working on another project. Unfortunately, precompiling the assets doesn't make any difference